# SQL - Query Timestamp into Buckets Crossing Midnight

Tags: sql, sql-server

My SQL experience is limited to basic queries and everything I've learned has been through Google-fu (mostly from this site), through trial and error, and out of necessity so please forgive my lack of clarity in my explanation.

Data: table dbo.[Offload] contains a unique identifier for each part [ID] and the [Timestamp] for when he part was completed.

Example data:

```
ID          TimeStamp
310963627   2018-01-10 15:30:21.000
310963562   2018-01-10 15:29:47.000
310963595   2018-01-10 15:29:04.000
310963517   2018-01-10 15:28:21.000
310963548   2018-01-10 15:27:41.000
310963469   2018-01-10 15:27:02.000
310963500   2018-01-10 15:26:17.000
310963436   2018-01-10 15:25:39.000
310963422   2018-01-10 15:24:58.000
```

> Edit: expanded sample data: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1JKnL-nWGcVWNpJarZ1u-vzQqopaf51vp

I have come up with a query that groups the count of parts produced by the shift and day of the time stamp of the row at the final station:

Shifts:

```
Shift   1st       2nd        3rd
Start   6:30 AM   2:30 PM    10:30 PM
End     2:30 PM   10:30 PM   6:30 AM
Hours   8:00      8:00       8:00
```

*3rd begins on the day before at 10:30PM
-ex: 2018-01-10:3rd = 2018-01-09 22:30:00.0000 to 2018-01-10 06:30:00.0000

```
SELECT  
        [Shift],
        Count([ID]) as Assembled

FROM(
    SELECT _60.*,
        CASE WHEN (
        CONVERT(CHAR(5), Timestamp, 114) between '06:30' and '14:30'
        ) 
                THEN LEFT(CAST(TimeStamp AS DATE),10)+':1st'

             WHEN (
        CONVERT(CHAR(5), Timestamp, 114) between '14:30' and '22:30'
        ) 
                THEN LEFT(CAST(TimeStamp AS DATE),10)+':2nd'

            WHEN (
        CONVERT(CHAR(5), Timestamp, 114) between '22:30' and '24:00'
        ) 
                THEN LEFT(CAST(DATEADD(DAY, 1, TimeStamp) AS DATE),10)+':3rd' 

            WHEN (
        CONVERT(CHAR(5), Timestamp, 114) between '00:00' and '06:30'
        ) 
                THEN LEFT(CAST(DATEADD(DAY, 0, TimeStamp) AS DATE),10)+':3rd'

           END AS [Shift]
    FROM dbo.Offload _60
) _60
where TimeStamp > (DATEADD(DAY, -150, GETDATE()))

GROUP BY    [Shift]
order by CAST(LEFT([shift],10) as date) desc
```

Current results:

```
Shift           Assembled
2018-01-10:1st  389
2018-01-10:2nd  39
2018-01-10:3rd  406
2018-01-09:1st  245
2018-01-09:2nd  334
2018-01-09:3rd  125
2018-01-08:1st  441
2018-01-08:2nd  263
2018-01-08:3rd  430
2018-01-07:1st  390
2018-01-07:2nd  456
2018-01-07:3rd  152
```

Desired results:

```
            1st 2nd 3rd
2018-01-10  389 39  406
2018-01-09  245 334 125
2018-01-08  441 263 430
2018-01-07  390 456 152
```

I'm not sure where to go from here; I don't know if some form of Pivot is my solution or something like [1](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1JKnL-nWGcVWNpJarZ1u-vzQqopaf51vp): [How to convert aggregation results into columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42424940/how-to-convert-aggregation-results-into-columns) "This" . I've tried grouping by date and 3rd breaks into two entries per day.

Comment: Some form of pivot should be what you're looking for, yes. Either with a `MAX` instead of the `SUM` in your link example (e.g. `MAX(CASE WHEN RIGHT(Shift, 3) = '1st' THEN Assembled END) ... GROUP BY SUBSTRING(Shift, 1, 10)` or with actual `PIVOT` syntax. I'd strongly recommend against concatenating the date and string into the `shift` column, though - it makes it harder for your pivot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating 2 columns [Shift] and [ShiftDate]; [Shift] identifies 1st, 2nd, 3rd and [ShiftDate] advances that part of 3rd that crosses midnight. Kris' answer got me on the right track. Thanks!

```
    CASE WHEN (CONVERT(CHAR(8), Timestamp, 114) between '06:30:00' and '14:30:00')        THEN '1'
         WHEN (CONVERT(CHAR(8), Timestamp, 114) between '14:30:00' and '22:30:00')        THEN '2'
         WHEN (CONVERT(CHAR(8), Timestamp, 114) between '22:30:00' and '24:00:00')        THEN '3'
         WHEN (CONVERT(CHAR(8), Timestamp, 114) between '00:00:00' and '06:30:00')        THEN '3'
              END AS [Shift]

   ,CASE WHEN (CONVERT(CHAR(8), Timestamp, 114) between '06:30:00' and '14:30:00')        THEN convert(varchar, CAST(TimeStamp AS DATE), 1)
         WHEN (CONVERT(CHAR(8), Timestamp, 114) between '14:30:00' and '22:30:00')        THEN convert(varchar, CAST(TimeStamp AS DATE), 1)
         WHEN (CONVERT(CHAR(8), Timestamp, 114) between '22:30:00' and '24:00:00')        THEN convert(varchar, CAST(DATEADD(DAY, 1, TimeStamp) AS DATE), 1)
         WHEN (CONVERT(CHAR(8), Timestamp, 114) between '00:00:00' and '06:30:00')        THEN convert(varchar, CAST(TimeStamp AS DATE), 1)
              END AS [ShiftDate]
```

Then group by:

```
  GROUP by [ShiftDate] ,[Shift]
  ORDER by [ShiftDate] desc
```

Answer (score 1):

This solution should work:

```
SELECT
    CAST(DATEADD(MINUTE, -390, TimeStamp) AS DATE) AS [Date]
    , SUM(CASE
        WHEN CAST(TimeStamp AS TIME) BETWEEN '06:30:00.000' AND '14:29:59.999'
        THEN 1 
        ELSE 0 
    END) AS [1st]
    , SUM(CASE 
        WHEN CAST(TimeStamp AS TIME) BETWEEN '14:30:00.000' AND '22:29:59.999'
        THEN 1 
        ELSE 0 
    END) AS [2nd]
    , SUM(CASE 
        WHEN CAST(TimeStamp AS TIME) < '06:30:00.000' 
            OR CAST(TimeStamp AS TIME) >= '22:30:00.000'
        THEN 1 
        ELSE 0 
    END) AS [3rd]
FROM Offload
GROUP BY CAST(DATEADD(MINUTE, -390, TimeStamp) AS DATE)
```

With a table looking like this (I added some other dates and times to test):

```
ID          TimeStamp
----------- -----------------------
310963422   2018-01-09 22:31:58.000
310963422   2018-01-09 23:52:30.000
310963422   2018-01-10 00:01:02.000
310963422   2018-01-10 04:08:45.000
310963422   2018-01-10 06:35:23.000
310963627   2018-01-10 15:30:21.000
310963562   2018-01-10 15:29:47.000
310963595   2018-01-10 15:29:04.000
310963517   2018-01-10 15:28:21.000
310963548   2018-01-10 15:27:41.000
310963469   2018-01-10 15:27:02.000
310963500   2018-01-10 15:26:17.000
310963436   2018-01-10 15:25:39.000
310963422   2018-01-10 15:24:58.000
310963500   2018-01-10 22:26:17.000
310963436   2018-01-10 22:25:39.000
310963422   2018-01-10 22:31:58.000
```

It will return results of

```
Date       1st         2nd         3rd
---------- ----------- ----------- -----------
2018-01-09 0           0           4
2018-01-10 1           11          1
```

**Just something to note:** I've made the assumption that the 10:30 PM to 6:30 AM shift is considered part of the *previous* day. If you want it to be part of the next day, get rid of the minus sign in `-390` inside the `DATEADD` functions.

Also consider replacing the `CASE` statements with [`IIF`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/logical-functions-iif-transact-sql) functions, I find it makes code more readable and SQL Server Management Studio doesn't like debugging problems with `CASE`.

If anything's unclear, leave a comment.

Comment: Thank you for your response, I was approaching this problem wrong, this is a much cleaner solution. One problem though is that the numbers for 2nd are skewed a bit. 1st and 3rd are now correct (checked manually), but 2nd is higher/lower than expected and I'm failing to figure out why. (expanded data set attached above)